Change the output of sphinx search to understand what words it found
I use the sphinx search engine and enter several words in the search using the "or" operator.
The search words can be in several fields and have different forms, differing from the searched one by the presence of additional characters. programming language - php
How can I split the overall output array according to the words found? Can I change the output of results in sphinx search , for example, make a grouping by the words found?
my request:
 (*1r0750*|*2w1223*|*lbl0010*)


Example of results output now:
[matches] => Array
        (
            [234612658] => Array
                (
                    [weight] => 3556
                    [attrs] => Array
                        (
                            [title] =>  CAT 1R0750
                            [vendor_code] => 1R0750
                            [replacements] => 
                            [description] => 1R0750 CAT 1R0750 
                        )

                )

            [375108963] => Array
                (
                    [weight] => 2553
                    [attrs] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => 2W 1223 / 2W1223 / 4N 0660 / 4N0660 CAT PMParts 
                            [vendor_code] => 2W 1223 / 2W1223
                            [replacements] => 
                            [description] => 
                        )

                )


